# How to filter the data provider for a tree?

Tags: apache-flex, filter, tree, filtering

I have a requirement to filter the tree similar to that of flex builder-->preferences wizard tree.

My tree dataprovider is arraycollection of industries. Each industry has a list of sub industries and further, say upto depth 5.

So when we type in a string to filter, only the node having this string along with their parent hierarchy should be returned.

How can we implement this using flex?

Answer (score 0):

I would write more but I think this link is all that's needed, essentially what it comes down to is you can use a filterFunction that's able to recursively act on the collection.  If you need more direction please specify where you're stuck and what your original data set looks like.

http://www.kalengibbons.com/blog/index.php/2009/01/filtering-a-flex-tree-using-an-arraycollection/